# How to put multiple entity fields inline as sub fields?

Tags: forms, entities, webforms

Not sure how to explain this so will add an image.

I want a field to have 2 values, one is the type of data, the other is how many, needs to be on the same line.

For example for a website, I need the client to be able to select the photo type, and then how many of them.

I'm using entity form, but a solution for webform also might work, although I prefer entity forms.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs)? It allows you to 1) create predefined sets of fields and 2) allows you to add fields that allow you to add those predefined fields. You have the option to restrict the paragraph selection as well as the number you can add.

A closely identical module is [Field Collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) although their project page suggests moving to Paragraphs instead.

It's not the two dropdowns you're looking for, but allows you to select a type and add as many as you want.

Comment: Not sure I understand...will paragraph work with entity forms?